# use order by in part of union statement

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

i want to sort one side of `union` statement like below code. but it's not possible to `order by` just part of `union` statement and when i use `view` for the part that has `order by`, it's make me some error about conflict in collate. so, how can i order by just one side of `union` statement?

```
   select Creator
        , CreateDate
        , Subject 
     from tblWkfTicket 
   where tblWkfTicket.ID = @tikectID
union 
   select Creator
        , CreateDate
        , '' AS Subject
     from tblWkfPost 
    where TicketID = @tikectID
 order by tblWkfPost.ID
        ;
```

Comment: There's no guarantee of the order in which results are returned from a `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`) query *unless* you have an `ORDER BY` that sorts the *entire* result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write an `ORDER BY` the applies to the *entire* result set. Assuming that you actually want the results from the first query to appear before the results from the second query, and for the results of the second query to be sorted by `ID`, you need to do something like:

```
select Creator,CreateDate,Subject
from
  (
   select Creator
       , CreateDate
       , Subject,
       , 1 as resSet
       , 0 as ID 
   from tblWkfTicket 
   where tblWkfTicket.ID = @tikectID
  union all
   select Creator
       , CreateDate
       , '' AS Subject
       , 2
       , ID
   from tblWkfPost 
   where TicketID = @tikectID
  ) t
order by
 resSet,
 ID;
```

Comment: I know i can order by the whole union statement but the problem is i want to put ticket first(the first part of union statement) and then sort other posts below the ticket.

Comment: @user1066713 - yes, that's what I've shown - but you *have* to write the `ORDER BY` to sort the entire result set. There's no guarantee (with `UNION` or `UNION ALL`) that the results from the first query will appear before the results of the second (or subsequent) queries. They could appear after, or could be interspersed throughout the results.

Comment: you're right. if i just order by one part of union statement there's no guarantee that the output has the order that i want. but why do you sort this statement by two parameter (resset and id)? i guess order by id is enough.

Comment: @user1066713 - `resset` is being used to make sure the results from the top query appear before the results from the bottom query. `id` is then being used to sort the results within each query (where the top query has a fixed `0` value for all rows, so if it returns multiple rows, their order is still undefined)

Comment: I still didn't get your point... if this query just order by id it's enough because the top query show first and then others show in sorted way.there's no need to use resset.

Comment: @user1066713 - I'm using it to *make sure* that the top query shows first. If you're guaranteed that all `id` values produced by the second query are > 0 then yes, okay, agreed, you don't need a separate condition. I always try to make sure that my queries don't have hidden assumptions in them.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   select *
     from (
                   select 1    seq
                        , null postid
                        , emb.Creator
                        , emb.CreateDate
                        , emb.Subject
                     from (         
                               select Creator
                                    , CreateDate
                                    , Subject 
                                 from tblWkfTicket 
                                where tblWkfTicket.ID = @tikectID
                          ) emb
               union all
                   select 2    seq
                        , tblWkfPost.IDpostid
                        , Creator
                        , CreateDate
                        , '' AS Subject
                    from tblWkfPost 
                   where TicketID = @tikectID
          )
order by seq
       , postid
;
```

which guarantees your ordering requirements

Comment: Once you introduce `seq` (or in my answer, `resSet`) you know that the two result sets are going to be distinct, so you may as well switch to `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: thanks, you're prefectly right, i've corrected my solution accordingly.